# Проверка списка с namedtuple

Tags: python, python-3.x, алгоритм, list

```
from collections import namedtuple

Person = namedtuple('Person', 'name, age')

People = [Person("Michael", 11), Person("Kristina", 11),
          Person("Pavel", 11), Person("Kolya", 11),
          Person("Nastya", 11), Person("Undefined", 12),
          Person("Ghost", 13)]
```

Как мне проверить что в списке People есть все люди с именем из списка имен `["Michael", "Kristina", "Pavel", "Kolya", "Nastya"]` и все они одного возраста, а так же вернуть все их имена с возрастом в в виде `"{name} {age}"`. Возраст не обязательно будет всегда 11 он может быть и другим.

Comment: какой результат вы ожидаете получить если не все имена из списка присутствуют в `Peoples`?

Comment: @MaxU Просто возвращать False

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Как мне проверить что в списке People есть все люди с именем из списка
> имен ["Michael", "Kristina", "Pavel", "Kolya", "Nastya"] и все они
> одного возраста,

```
print(set(names).issubset(set(p.name for p in People)) and len(set(p.age for p in People if p.name in names)) == 1)
```

> А так же вернуть все их имена с возрастом в в виде "{name} {age}".

```
print(",".join(f"{p.name} {p.age}" for p in People if p.name in names))
```

Но вообще это довольно простое задание, хотя решать его можно разными способами.

Comment: А так же вернуть все их имена с возрастом в в виде "{name} {age}".

Имелось введу вернуть тех которые нашлись в списк из списка имен) Сам запутался уже :D

Comment: проверил ваш, но почему-то он возвращает False

Comment: @Cookie Ну в принципе я привёл код всех конструкций, которые вам для этого понадобятся. Выборка будет как в последнем куске кода: `p for p in People if p.name in names`, вам осталось только напечатать/вернуть нужные поля.

Comment: @Cookie Да, я немного запутался, что в чём должно быть код не совсем такой будет.

Comment: https://sun9-36.userapi.com/YJxzGH6fLs39R4Au3RcQ_VGyoJhHWGrwB9nEjw/Aj1oN2YsQ1c.jpg

Вот хотя должно быть True

Comment: @Cookie Я исправил код. Но вообще если это учебное задание вы должны его делать сами )

Comment: спасибо, нет я просто делаю покер, и на основе этого алгоритма я буду высчитывать комбинацию рояль флэш)

Answer (score 1):

```
#Данный словарь будет иметь вид:
#{
#    имя_1 : возраст,
#    имя_2 : возраст,
#    имя_3 : возраст,
#    ...
#}
d = dict(People)

#По очереди перебираем имена из списка `names` и проверяем, 
#есть ли данное имя в словаре `d` и равен ли возраст этого человека
#возрасту первого человека в списке.
if all(name in d and d[name] == d[names[0]] for name in names):
     #Если проверка пройдена, печатаем.
     #Так как известно, что возраст у всех одинаковый,
     #можно брать возраст любого человека из списка, например первого.
     for name in names:
        print(f"{name} {d[names[0]]}")
```

**Минус** этого решения - вариант со словарём возможен только для кортежей с двумя элементами.

**Результат**

```
Michael 11
Kristina 11
Pavel 11
Kolya 11
Nastya 11
```